# Trying to serve HTML5 <audio> element from Python+SSL to Android Chrome

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, ssl, audio

I have a Python-based web application server; everything was great
with plain HTTP.  With HTTPS, everything works perfectly with
all browsers--except Android Chrome.  With Chrome, HTML and icons are fine
over HTTPS, but the <audio> element fails to start.  I see
Chrome pull one initial byte of the mp3 (presumably its way of testing file
presence), which is served back to it.  And then Chrome greys out
the `<audio>` element.

I've pulled that same single byte using curl, and it works fine:

curl -r 0-1 -k https://localhost:8083/foo.mp3 > foo1.mp3

I've added various delays and flushes, without fixing the problem.

It would seem to not be a content-range issue, as I've also
changed the code to return the full mp3 (with 200 code), with
the same Chrome behavior.

Firefox is happy with it (both Android and Linux), as is Midori (a
Webkit based browser).  On Linux, Chrome/Chromium are both happy with
it.  Android Chrome--no luck.

I've extracted just the relevant bits of code; I'm assuming there's
some HTTP nicety I'm missing (and, believe me, I've been looking).
To exercise it, plug in a self-signed certificate pair at the
hard-coded files "server.key" and "server.crt".  Then put an mp3
of your choice at "foo.mp3" and point your browser at:

```
https://localhost:8083
```

TIA for any suggestions!  I'm sorry the code runs a little long;
I extracted just the bits to reproduce this.  I almost left off
the range support, but didn't want to chase legacy code paths
of Chrome.

```
#
# debug.py
#       Sample code snippet to debug Chrome HTML5 <audio> SSL problem
#
import pdb
import sys, socket, ssl, threading, os, time
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

OURMP3 = "foo.mp3"

# Decode a "range:" header option, return
#  (offset,length) or None if we don't like
#  the region (TBD, multiple ranges and
#  multipart)
# We're passed the file's os.stat as well as
#  the range: field value.
def decode_range(st, range):
    # Byte units, please
    if not range.startswith("bytes="):
        return None
    range = range[6:]

    # Single range
    if ',' in range:
        return None

    # Start to offset
    if range[0] == '-':
        range = range[1:]
        if not range.isdigit():
            return None
        val1 = int(range)
        if val1 >= st.st_size:
            return None
        return (0, val1)

    # Offset to end...
    elif range[-1] == '-':
        range = range[:-1]
        if not range.isdigit():
            return None
        val2 = int(range)
        if val2 >= st.st_size:
            return None
        return (val2, st.st_size - val2)

    # Offset1 to offset2
    else:
        parts = range.split('-')
        if len(parts) != 2:
            return None
        if not all(p.isdigit() for p in parts):
            return None
        val1 = int(parts[0])
        val2 = int(parts[1])
        if val1 >= val2:
            return None
        return (val1, val2-val1)

class Client(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # Send the mp3 file OURMP3
    def send_mp3(self):

        # For simplicity, just a big buffer
        f = open(OURMP3, "rb")
        st = os.fstat(f.fileno())
        buf = f.read()
        f.close()

        # Partial
        ranged = 'range' in self.headers
        if ranged:
            tup = decode_range(st, self.headers['range'])
            assert tup
            startoff,nbyte = tup
            assert (nbyte + startoff) <= len(buf)
            self.send_response(206)
        else:
            startoff = 0
            nbyte = len(buf)
            self.send_response(200)

        # Headers
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "audio/mpeg")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", nbyte)
        if ranged:
            self.send_header("Content-Range",
             "bytes %d-%d/%d" % (startoff, startoff+nbyte-1, st.st_size))
        self.send_header("Last-Modified",
         time.asctime(time.localtime(st.st_mtime)))
        self.end_headers()

        # Let our upper layers write it back (or discard
        #  it, for HEAD)
        return buf[startoff:(startoff+nbyte)]

    # Send an HTML5 <audio> player for our mp3
    def send_root(self):
        buf = \
'''
<html><head><title>Test MP3</title></head>\r
Audio player:<br>\r
<body><audio src="foo.mp3" controls autoplay></audio></body>\r
</html>\r
'''
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(buf))
        self.end_headers()
        return buf

    # Process HTTP GET's
    def do_GET(self):
        sys.stderr.write("GET %r\n" % (self.path,))
        path = self.path

        # Root; our HTML to play the mp3
        if (not path) or (path == '/'):
            buf = self.send_root()

        # Our mp3
        elif path.endswith(OURMP3):
            buf = self.send_mp3()

        # That's all we serve
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            return None

        # Body?
        if buf:
            self.wfile.write(buf)

# Dispatch this web client
def serve_client(conn, tup):
    h = Client(conn, tup, None)
    conn.close()
    sys.exit(0)

# Endless server loop on port 8083
def server():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
        "server.key", "server.crt",
        server_side=True, suppress_ragged_eofs=False,
        do_handshake_on_connect=False)

    s.bind( ("", 8083) )
    s.listen(10)
    while True:
        conn,tup = s.accept()
        sys.stderr.write("client %r\n" % (tup,))
        conn.do_handshake()
        t = threading.Thread(target=serve_client, args=(conn,tup))
        t.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server()
```

Comment: I suggest to set up another (working) web server like Nginx and uWSGI. Server the file over that server. Assuming it works use Wireshark to do HTTP response binary diff between your in-house server and known good web server.